# What is the equivalent configuration for Azure SQL database for an on-premise server of 2 TB RAM?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I am new to Azure and we are working on migrating from on-premise to Azure SQL Database.
In the on-premise we have server with 48 cores and 2 TB RAM.

What would be the corresponding configuration on Azure? or How to determine the correct configuration whether to use DTU, vCore (General Purpose/Hyperscale) etc

I have currently chosen a vCore Model with Hyperscale Service tier and instance of 40 vCores.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is an incredibly complex question which has far too many facets to be properly answered here.  Azure sales support is best qualified to look at your specific technical needs and make suggestions accordingly.

That said, based on your memory needs alone, you are most likely going to be directed toward the M-Series setups rather than the General Purpose.

Single Database:
[image: Single Database]

Elastic Pool:
[image: Elastic Pool]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to do the following

- Run Data Migration Assistant to validate if the database can in fact migrate to Azure SQL DB
- There is an option to assess which tier should your database should go to by capturing data. Then you can use Powershell to convert the data in HTML format
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-sku-recommend-sql-db?view=sql-server-ver15
- I would not advise going to hyperscale because the performance of Hyperscale is similar to General Purpose as compared to Business Critical. The biggest benefit of Hyperscale is that you can expand database more than 100 TB and add many read replica.

The reason I caution because if you start with General Purpose, you can move it to Business Critical and vice versa. Going to Hyperscale is one way street. You cannot go back!